# how to add regex validation to a data field when different options are selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to add regex validation to a data field so when the sms option is chosen the validation is applied to the data field and when the email option is chosen validation is also applied.

**cshtml file**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-7">
                            MType
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-control-wrap col-md-10 date-of-birth-form-control-wrap">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                @{ var selectList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MTypeEnum))
                                       .Cast<MTypeEnum>()
                                       .Where(e => e != MTypeEnume.Uninitialised)
                                       .Select(e => new SelectListItem
                                       {
                                           Value = ((int) e).ToString(),
                                           Text = e.ToString()
                                       });
                                }
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.DataType, selectList, new { @class = "form-control", @onChange="check()" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataType)

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-7">
                            Data
                        </label>
                        <div class="form-control-wrap col-sm-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data, new { @class = "form-control", @name ="Data", @id="Data", @onkeyup = "enablebutton(this)" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data)
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
```

**Model file**

```
 [RegularExpression(@"[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address. ")]
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public MTypeEnum DataType { get; set; }
```

Any Idea on how to go about this, please?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to validate using regex on the server?  Is there some reason that you don't want to validate before the form gets sent to the server with jQuery or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add validation when select "sms" or or "email",you can use client side validation,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public string Data { get; set; }
public MTypeEnum DataType { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<form>
    <select class="form-control" onChange="check()" name="DataType" id="DataType">
        <option value="sms">sms</option>
        <option value="email">email</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
    <input asp-for="Data" class = "form-control" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

js:

```
<script>
    function check() {
        if ($("#DataType").val() == "sms" || $("#DataType").val() == "email") {
            $("#Data").attr("pattern", "[A-Za-z]{3}");
            $("#Data").attr("title", "Three letter country code");
        } else {
            $("#Data").removeAttr("pattern");
            $("#Data").removeAttr("title");

        }
    }
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution complete with error messages for the user to try and correct their errors before they try submitting their mobile number and email address data to the server.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submitFormID').on('submit', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var errorCount = 0;
        $('span.errorMessage').text('');

        $('input').each(function(){

            var $this = $(this);
            
            if($this.val() === ''){
                var error = 'Please fill ' + $this.prev('label').text(); 
                $this.next('span').text(error);
                errorCount = errorCount + 1;   
            }
        });

        if(errorCount === 0){

            var mobileNumber = $('input[name=MNumber]').val();

            var email = $('input[name=Email]').val();


            var regEmail = /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i;
            var regMobile = /^([+]\d{2}[ ])?\d{10}$/;

            if (regEmail.test(email) == false) {
              $('input[name=Email]').next('span').text('Email address is invalid!');
              errorCount = errorCount + 1; 
            } else {

                if(isNaN(parseFloat(mobileNumber )) && !isFinite(mobileNumber ) && regMobile.test(mobileNumber) ) {
                    var error = 'Mobile number incorect.';
                    $('input[name=MNumber]').next('span').text(error);
                    errorCount = errorCount + 1; 
                }
                else {
                if(!errorCount) {
                     $(this)[0].submit(); 
                     }
                   
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#" id="submitFormID">
    <p>
        <label>Mobile</label>
        <input type="text" name="MNumber"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="Email"/>
        <span class="errorMessage"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="thesubmitBtn" type="submit" value="submit me"> 
    </p>
</form>
```